# NIPhotoAlbumScrollView: unable to adjust image after device rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nimbus-ios

I'm using **NIPhotoAlbumScrollView** from [Nimbus framework](http://jverkoey.github.com/nimbus/index.html) 
and once I rotate the device the image displayed loses its central position... have someone used this component and faced my same situation?

ps: I'm using **(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)** mask for both **NIPhotoAlbumScrollView** and its **NIPagingScrollViewPage**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call these methods of your NIPhotoAlbumScrollView in corresponding view controller methods

```
- willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
- willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

Like this

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation { return YES; }

    //====================================================================================================
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation duration: (NSTimeInterval) duration
    {
        [super               willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: toInterfaceOrientation duration: duration];
        [self.photoAlbumView willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: toInterfaceOrientation duration: duration];
    }


//====================================================================================================
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
                                          duration: (NSTimeInterval) duration
{
    [super               willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: interfaceOrientation duration: duration];
    [self.photoAlbumView willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: interfaceOrientation duration: duration];
}
```

Docs http://latest.docs.nimbuskit.info/interface_n_i_paging_scroll_view.html#a3cd8024a82d09f24019ea916551904c4

Comment: I don't understand how this can fix the problem... what should I do in that methods? (anyway I temporarily solved by calling "reloadData" after the rotation... but I know that this is not the best solution)

Comment: These methods prepare your photo album view for rotation. Calling them in my UIViewController subclass solved the problem for me.